# Datapicker Format and Date format to Parse to URL

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I need help in having two date formats for my datepicker.

Initially when shown on the browser i need to be in Europe format dd-mm-yy but when i pass it on the URL i need it to be in a yy-mm-dd format so the booking system can recognise it. is this possible.

my backend is wordpress so i am using the default calendar datepicker of wordpress.

```
<form action="http://localhost/booking/" method="GET" class="">
<input type="hidden" name="Op" value="SetState" />
 <p class="acontact left calendar">
 Check-in Date<br>
<span class="checkin"><input type="text" name="DateFrom" value="2016-04-05" size="40" class="MyDate" name="MyDate_a" aria-required="true" id="dp1457978166549" style="width:150px;"> </span>
</p>

<p class="acontact left calendar">
Check-out Date<br>
<span class="checkout"><input type="text" name="DateTo" value="2016-04-08" size="40" class="MyDate" name="MyDate_b" aria-required="true" id="dp1457978166550" style="width:150px;"> </span>
</p>

<div class="button"><input class="request" name="anfrage" type="submit" value="Check Booking"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.MyDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
});
```

I am not familiar with javascript so your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:-->Check this code, I had made changes in date values, they are in dd-mm-yy format, but after pressing button, they will be displayed in yy-mm-dd format, also check requested URL:

```
<form action="http://localhost/booking/" method="GET" class="">    
<input type="hidden" name="Op" value="SetState" />
<p class="acontact left calendar">
Check-in Date<br>
<span class="checkin"><input type="text" name="DateFrom" value="13-12-2016" size="40" class="MyDate" aria-required="true" id="dp1457978166549" style="width:150px;"> </span>
</p>

<p class="acontact left calendar">
Check-out Date<br>
<span class="checkout"><input type="text" name="DateTo" value="14-12-2016" size="40" class="MyDate" aria-required="true" id="dp1457978166550" style="width:150px;"> </span>
</p>

<div class="button"><input class="request" name="anfrage" type="submit" onClick="runf()" value="Check Booking"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function runf() {
var d1 = document.getElementsByName("DateFrom")[0].value;
var d2 = document.getElementsByName("DateTo")[0].value;
alert("DateFrom Before: "+d1);
var segments = d1.split('-');

d1 = segments[2] + '-' + segments[1] + '-' + segments[0];

document.getElementsByName("DateFrom")[0].value=d1;

alert("DateFrom After: "+d1);
alert("DateTo Before: "+d2);
segments=d2.split('-');

d2 = segments[2] + '-' + segments[1] + '-' + segments[0];

document.getElementsByName("DateTo")[0].value=d2;

alert("DateTo After: "+d2);
```

}

Comment: Your code seems to show an alert box of the updated date format but only for one field. also, i need to pass the yy-mm-dd format to the URL. but your code seems to pass the original format dd-mm-yy. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue ussing alfField and altFormat properties and including a new input hidden to store the alternative format:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.MyDate').datepicker({
      dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
      altField: "#alternative_input_id",
      altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

By doing this you can take your desired format from the new input type hidden.

Wish it help you!

Regards

Edit: I see you have two text input and you make the datepicker by class. Using the method I have post you need to set ID to each text input you have and then declare datepicker twice, one per input text (and creating two hidden input):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#dp1457978166549').datepicker({
      dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
      altField: "#alternative_input_id_1",
      altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
   });
   $('#dp1457978166550').datepicker({
      dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
      altField: "#alternative_input_id_2",
      altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
   });
});
```

Comment: did not seem to work it still pass the same date format as dd-mm-yy

Comment: May be you have to set the name attribute "DateFrom" and "DateTo" into the new hidden inputs. You will have two text inputs working with datepicker and showing dd-mm-yy format, and two hidden inputs with yy-mm-dd format.